# Recording a 1280x720 video holding the phone in portrait orientation

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I am struggling to record a video in a landscape resolution (1280x720) holding my phone in portrait orientation using the cameraX API (I also wasn't able to do it with any of the APIs, neither camera1 nor camera2). I was able to make it work for the ImageCapture use case and the preview though. The video keeps getting recorded in the nearest possible portrait resolution. Any help is appreciated!

```
CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
   .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
   .build();

Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
   .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
   .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
   .build();
preview.setSurfaceProvider(mVideoView.createSurfaceProvider());

ImageCapture.Builder imageCaptureBuilder = new ImageCapture.Builder();
mImageCapture = imageCaptureBuilder
   .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
   .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
   .build();

VideoCapture.Builder videoCaptureBuilder = new VideoCapture.Builder();
mVideoCapture = videoCaptureBuilder
   .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
   .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
   .build();

ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
   RecordMediaCameraXActivity.this,
   cameraSelector,
   preview,
   mImageCapture,
   mVideoCapture
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that the device supports the resolution you're looking for.

Basically, you want a resolution that looks like this:

```
4:3 full sensor
   |---------+========+---------|
   |         : 9:16   :         |
   |         : 720p   :         |
   |         : crop   :         |
   |         :        :         |
   |         :        :         |
   |         :        :         |
   |         :        :         |
   |         :        :         |
   |---------+========+---------|
```

and that's just not something most devices support.  They only support crops that are in the same alignment as the image sensor:

```
4:3 full sensor
   |----------------------------|
   |                            |
   +============================+
   : 16:9 720p crop             :
   :                            :
   :                            :
   :                            :
   +============================+
   |                            |
   |----------------------------|
```

If you want this, you'll likely need to crop the frames from the camera yourself.
That'd require using something like ImageAnalysis or Preview to the GPU, and directly feeding a MediaRecorder or MediaCodec/MediaMuxer with the results.

Also, CameraX doesn't yet officially support video recording, so it's possible that it'll support this kind of use case when it's officially available, but I wouldn't count on that.

Comment: If you say that crops are only supported if they are in the same alignment as the sensor, how come the preview and the ImageCapture use case do otherwise? I didn't know that video recording is not yet fully supported, so maybe I can still hope for something in the future.

The only possibility to access the video or preview stream that I found was to call "getBitmap()" on the PreviewView? Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Those use cases crop on the app end of things (PreviewView by setting a transform matrix that removes the excess area).  You can use the ImageAnalysis use case to receive image frames from the camera directly.